# Trying to get Django running on a VPS but I keep running into "Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition"

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

So, as the question says, I am trying to deploy Django onto a VPS, but I keep getting the error "Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition". I have tried going to the mod_wsgi website and looking at the example code for daemon deployment but that doesn't help. I also tried using the Django website, but the instructions are not specific enough to my problem. The error logs also don't really show anything helpful, because they don't specify which part of the code has a syntax error, just which line!

Here is the error message I get when I try to restart my apache server:

```
Syntax error on line 34 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com:
Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition.
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Here is some relevant version information:

```
Apache Version: 2.2.22
Ubuntu Version: 12.02
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

If there is anything else I should add, please let me know. I am also running python and Django in a virtual environment.

Here is my apach2.conf file without comments:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers    5
MaxClients        10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers       1
MinSpareThreads    1
MaxSpareThreads    4
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients        10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
StartServers       1
MinSpareThreads    1
MaxSpareThreads    4
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients        10
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

User www-data
Group www-data

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>


DefaultType None


HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel info

Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

Include httpd.conf

Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

Include conf.d/

Include sites-enabled/
```

And here is my virtual hosts file (domain obfuscated):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/mysiteenv/static/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mysiteenv/static/favicon.ico

        Alias /media/ /var/www/mysiteenv/media
        Alias /static/ /var/www/mysiteenv/static

        <Directory /var/www/mysiteenv/static>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/mysiteenv/media>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/var/www/mysiteenv python-path=/var/www
        WSGIProcessGroup example.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/mysiteenv/mysite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/mysiteenv>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my error log:

```
[Fri Mar 10 18:30:20 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 10 18:30:20 2017] [info] Server built: Jul 15 2016 15:32:34
[Fri Mar 10 18:30:20 2017] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Mar 10 18:30:20 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14581): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:30:20 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14581`enter code here`): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:32:43 2017] [error] [client 107.142.156.166] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico, referer: http://example.com/
[Fri Mar 10 18:32:43 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 107.142.156.166] Zlib: Compressed 302 to 229 : URL /favicon.ico, referer: http://example.com/
[Fri Mar 10 18:32:44 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14585): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:32:44 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14585): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14585): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14585): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14581): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14581): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14581): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14585): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14585): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14581): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] Server built: Jul 15 2016 15:32:34
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14590): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:33:02 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14590): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:35:20 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14590): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 18:35:20 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14590): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:35:20 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14590): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:35:20 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14590): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 18:35:20 2017] [info] removed PID file /var/run/apache2.pid (pid=14580)
[Fri Mar 10 18:35:20 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:40 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:40 2017] [info] Server built: Jul 15 2016 15:32:34
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:40 2017] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:40 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:40 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Create interpreter 'www.example.com|'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [info] [client 218.30.103.18] mod_wsgi (pid=14735, process='', application='www.example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [error] [client 218.30.103.18] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [error] [client 218.30.103.18] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [error] [client 218.30.103.18] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [error] [client 218.30.103.18]   File "/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [error] [client 218.30.103.18]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [error] [client 218.30.103.18] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Fri Mar 10 18:39:54 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 218.30.103.18] Zlib: Compressed 627 to 382 : URL /
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [info] [client 146.120.166.33] mod_wsgi (pid=14735, process='', application='www.example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [error] [client 146.120.166.33] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [error] [client 146.120.166.33] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [error] [client 146.120.166.33] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [error] [client 146.120.166.33]   File "/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [error] [client 146.120.166.33]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:56 2017] [error] [client 146.120.166.33] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [info] [client 146.120.158.107] mod_wsgi (pid=14735, process='', application='www.example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [error] [client 146.120.158.107] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [error] [client 146.120.158.107] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [error] [client 146.120.158.107] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [error] [client 146.120.158.107]   File "/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [error] [client 146.120.158.107]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Mar 10 18:40:57 2017] [error] [client 146.120.158.107] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Destroy interpreter 'www.example.com|'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14735): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [info] removed PID file /var/run/apache2.pid (pid=14732)
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:38 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [info] Server built: Jul 15 2016 15:32:34
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Python home /var/www/mysiteenv.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:41:39 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Adding '/var/www/mysiteenv' to path.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:00 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:00 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:00 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:01 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14801): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:01 2017] [info] removed PID file /var/run/apache2.pid (pid=14798)
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:01 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [info] Server built: Jul 15 2016 15:32:34
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [debug] prefork.c(1023): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Python home /var/www/mysiteenv.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:42:10 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Adding '/var/www/mysiteenv' to path.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Create interpreter 'www.example.com|'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Adding '/var/www/mysiteenv' to path.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] [client 141.8.143.220] mod_wsgi (pid=14840, process='', application='www.example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Python home /var/www/mysiteenv.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Initializing Python.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Adding '/var/www/mysiteenv' to path.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:05 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.ctcindia.co.in'. You may need to add u'www.ctcindia.co.in' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:09 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Create interpreter 'www.example.com|'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:09 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Adding '/var/www/mysiteenv' to path.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:09 2017] [info] [client 141.8.143.141] mod_wsgi (pid=14870, process='', application='www.example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/mysiteenv/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:10 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.ctcindia.co.in'. You may need to add u'www.ctcindia.co.in' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 18:43:10 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 141.8.143.141] Zlib: Compressed 57817 to 9325 : URL /
[Fri Mar 10 18:46:02 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.unitedengitech.com'. You may need to add u'www.unitedengitech.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 18:46:06 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.unitedengitech.com'. You may need to add u'www.unitedengitech.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 18:46:06 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 141.8.143.141] Zlib: Compressed 58028 to 9342 : URL /favicon.ico
[Fri Mar 10 18:49:31 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'www.arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 18:49:31 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 66.249.66.181] Zlib: Compressed 57902 to 9325 : URL /robots.txt
[Fri Mar 10 18:49:31 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'www.arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 18:49:31 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 66.249.66.175] Zlib: Compressed 58218 to 9367 : URL /pro/gold_purity.aspx
[Fri Mar 10 19:01:44 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:01:44 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 107.142.156.166] Zlib: Compressed 58204 to 9420 : URL /
[Fri Mar 10 19:01:45 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:01:45 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 107.142.156.166] Zlib: Compressed 58308 to 9419 : URL /favicon.ico, referer: http://arcinstruments.com/
[Fri Mar 10 19:06:49 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:06:49 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 107.142.156.166] Zlib: Compressed 58204 to 9416 : URL /
[Fri Mar 10 19:06:49 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:06:49 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 107.142.156.166] Zlib: Compressed 58308 to 9414 : URL /favicon.ico, referer: http://arcinstruments.com/
[Fri Mar 10 19:07:29 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:07:34 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'arcinstruments.com'. You may need to add u'arcinstruments.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:07:34 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 141.8.143.212] Zlib: Compressed 57817 to 9329 : URL /
[Fri Mar 10 19:08:17 2017] [error] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.unitedengitech.com'. You may need to add u'www.unitedengitech.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[Fri Mar 10 19:08:17 2017] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 157.55.39.100] Zlib: Compressed 58407 to 9451 : URL /client.php
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Destroy interpreter 'www.example.com|'.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Destroying interpreters.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Destroy interpreter 'www.example.com|'.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Terminating Python.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14840): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:25 2017] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=14870): Python has shutdown.
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:26 2017] [info] removed PID file /var/run/apache2.pid (pid=14839)
[Fri Mar 10 19:14:26 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Also, I have no idea where those other domains came from. Thank you for the help, if there is any more information you need please tell me and I will edit my post. I have been trying to fix this for weeks and I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using mod_wsgi 3.3. That is well over 50 versions behind and over 5 years old. You shouldn't be using such an old version. It isn't supported and depending on whether the operating system package used had patched it, may have a potential security vulnerability in it.

If you for some reason you can't upgrade, try changing:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/var/www/mysiteenv python-path=/var/www
```

to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www:/var/www/mysiteenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what finally got the apache server to properly reload, and also, running sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi says it is already the latest version so I'm not sure how to update. Also, now the apache server reloads, but visiting the site results in a 500 internal server error, do you know how to fix that? Sorry if that is outside your scope and thank you for your help :-)

Comment: If you are stuck with mod_wsgi 3.3, you are using a very old operating system version. You shouldn't use such an old operating system version. For 500 errors, check Apache error log. Also setup Django to log details of internal exceptions, or temporarily enable ``DEBUG=True`` in Django settings so error comes back to browser.